# jQuery function in time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this jQuery code to animate two `div`'s and and when the page load the divs are already there .Then it start the animation. How do I hide the div when the page load and start this animation after few seconds one after the other.

Here is the process that I am expecting

(page load -> after few seconds -> `#float img` load -> after few seconds- >`#floatbubble` load)

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var effect_selector = "#float img";
        $(effect_selector).height(0);
        $(effect_selector).width(0);
        $(effect_selector).animate({ width: 125, height : 125 },"slow",function(){
            $(effect_selector).removeAttr("style");

            //Another effect
            var effect_selector = "#floatbubble";
            $(effect_selector).height(0);
            $(effect_selector).width(0);
            $(effect_selector).animate({ width: 125, height : 125 },"slow",function(){
                $(effect_selector).removeAttr("style");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4kq561/)

Comment: Wrap your code in a setTimeout

Comment: aha sure I'll try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      var effect_selector = "#float img";
      var effect_selector2 = "#floatbubble";
      $(effect_selector).css({'height':'0px','width':'0px'});
      $(effect_selector2).css({'height':'0px','width':'0px'});
      $(window).load(function(){
        $(effect_selector).delay(2000).animate({ width: '125px', height : '125px' },"slow",function(){
            $(effect_selector).removeAttr("style");

            //Another effect
            $(effect_selector2).delay(2000).animate({ width: '125px', height : '125px' },"slow",function(){
                $(effect_selector2).removeAttr("style");
            });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Using `delay` certainly makes for more readable code then `window.setTimeout`

Comment: @AndrewShepherd that's true

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(function () {
    setTimeout(function functionName() {
        firstAnimation();
    }, 2000)
});

function firstAnimation() {
    var effect_selector = "#float img";
    $(effect_selector).height(0);
    $(effect_selector).width(0);
    $(effect_selector).animate({ width: 125, height: 125 }, "slow", function () {
        $(effect_selector).removeAttr("style");

        setTimeout(function functionName() {
            secondAnimation();
        }, 2000)
    });
}
function secondAnimation() {
    var effect_selector = "#floatbubble";
    $(effect_selector).height(0);
    $(effect_selector).width(0);
    $(effect_selector).animate({ width: 125, height: 125 }, "slow", function () {
        $(effect_selector).removeAttr("style");
    });
}
```

This will help you

Comment: I believe he wants both animations to run 2 seconds after each other not both running just 2 seconds after the page load